# connection to mongo db failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

failed to to connect to mongo. Very new to this need help please.

this is what i get:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: test
2016-09-12T00:09:34.516+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
2016-09-12T00:09:34.517+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format your posts to make it easier to read. There's no need to say "need help please", that's assumed when you post a question. Have you verified that mongo is running on the same machine you're running the shell on?

Comment: Not sure how to check. I have just started to do a tutorial but having these errors.

Comment: what platform are you running on? try `ps aux | grep mongod` and verify you have a running process

Comment: Im running this in win10 and im using cmd

Comment: So did you verify that the mongo service was running?

Comment: clearly mongodb isn't running. Either start mongod.exe or run it as a service.

Comment: As stated mongo is not running, check here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: Yes, thank you guys. I was trying to help this person get to that conclusion themselves

Comment: Thanks guys. i should of checked that at first. Its working now.